# Software designing process with UML

Tags: uml

When designing for a software, what is the correct order of UML diagrams we have to do? Starting from the Use Case diagram, what would be the next diagrams until we have enough to start coding?

Comment: There are dozens of books out there detailing various design processes. You can't expect a meaningful answer in 2 or 3 paragraphs here.

Comment: The question is definitely too broad. Moreover, there is simply no such thing as the correct order of UML diagrams. Even UC doesn't necessarily have to be the first one. Reading some good books about analysis with UML is definitely strongly recommended. Note that someone may say this comment is an answer. Well, technically I am not answering the question, but rather challenging it.

Comment: Just two starting points: go for RUP (or don't) if you want a lengthy process. Look for ICONIX for a very dense approach.

Comment: @Ister Yes I admit my question is a bit too broad. Sorry.. I remember when I was in a project class we had to start from collecting requirements and translate them into use case diagram. from there we built component diagram and from component diagram we built class diagram. My assumption is each diagram is based on different diagram which to my conclusion there might be some sort of "order" to build all these UML diagrams.

Comment: @qwerty_so can you please recommend one good book? RUP might be a bit too big for my use case, hence I'm seeking a basic design processes (not as simple as the plain old SDLC). Something like, "to design your database, you need A and B diagrams, and from these diagrams you can start structuring your application by building C, D and E diagrams" Some bare minimum process that is already proven and used by many software architects.

Comment: Just google for ICONIX. That once put me on rails with UML. Be warned that those rails stretch far until you reach the first intermediate stops. Having a good UML tool will help a lot.

Comment: @qwerty_so this looks simple enough for me to get going https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/imported/135-ICONIXProcessDiagram2.jpg Thank you very much!

Comment: See also http://agilemodeling.com/essays/phasesExamined.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UML is just a modeling language, not a software development methodology. A well-known methodology that provides guidelines for using UML in its software development process is the Rational Unified Process, although its popularity has declined. Still, it is not easy to determine the order of the UML diagrams prescribed by RUP from the available material provided by IBM. I have written a paper http://admiraalit.nl/admiraal/WhichUMLmodels.pdf which may help you with that.

For a simple application, a class diagram and a component diagram may be enough, but it depends very much on the type of application.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am aware of the UML is not a development methodology. I understand that all these methodologies are based on SDLC and I am especially interested in the "D" Design part. 
If let's say I am alone building a simple employee attendance recording system for an X Company, after I have collected, elicited all the requirements, put them all in UC diagrams, what is the next diagrams to be built based on that UC diagrams? and what would be the next diagrams based on that diagrams? and so forth.. In general, what is the "core" process to architect a system?

Comment: There isn't any widely accepted core process for UML modeling. Personally, for a simple administrative system, I would create a UI overview using a state machine diagram, where each state represents a screen (web page). Then, I would create a class diagram representing the physical database structure (one class per table) and a component diagram. That's all.